# Error in django url.py?

Tags: django

I am new in django. I try to practice and run the wiki application (i found tutorial at http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1100000&fromSeriesID=110">Learn django), In url.py file i write the following urls...

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    (r'^wikicamp/(?p<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.edit_page'),
    (r'^wikicamp/(?p<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.save_page'),
    (r'^wikicamp/(?p<page_name>[^/]+)/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.view_page'),
)
```

But there is errror which i cant understand.

```
sre_Constants.error:Unexpected end of pattern.
  (r'^wikicamp/(?p<page_name>[^/]+)/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.view_page'),
```

I use the Django-1.0.2-final.tar.gz

Answer (score 6):

You need to use an uppercase `P` to capture named regexp groups:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    (r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.edit_page'),
    (r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.save_page'),
    (r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$','wikiapp.wiki.views.view_page'),
)
```